# MySQL relation on multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have the following tables:

```
 Makes:
 id - make_name

 Models:
 id - model_name - make_id

 Trims:
 id - trim_name - model_id

 Forsale_Cars:
 id - trim_id - year - price
```

My question is, if the user selects the (Make ID) how can I return all the trims listed under that make and exist in the Forsale_Cars table as well?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Eloquent this will work for you:

```
$make = Make::find($selectedId);
$trims = $make->trims()->has('forsales')->get();
// returns collection of Trim models that have related row in foresale_cars

// to also load the forsales models you can then do this (load on the collection):
$trims->load('forsales');
// or instead in one chain
$trims = $make->trims()->has('forsales')->with('forsales')->get();
```

You need this relation on `Make` model:

```
public function trims()
{
  return $this->hasManyThrough('Trim', 'Model');
}
```

other relations like in your previous question [MySQL relation with multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23250102/mysql-relation-with-multiple-tables#answer-23250669)

Comment: Thanks again, one more thing please, if I want to get the rows from Forsale table that belongs to the specified make? Thanks again

Comment: Check the edit. You can do it later qith `load` or in the same place using `with`

Comment: Thanks a lot, where can I read more about elqouent functions with laravel please? the Laravel official docs does not cover it all!

Comment: http://laravel.com/api/4.1 or 4.2 or simply use the framework code you have in your project.

Answer (score 0):

You want to show trims. So select from trims. You want to show only trims that exist in Forsale_Cars, so use EXISTS (or IN, if you think in sets). You want to show only trims of certain makes. Again use EXISTS (or IN), because you can word it so: where exists the model with the specified make (or where the model is in the set of models of that make).

Hope this helps. Otherwise come back with what you got, so we can give you more advice.

Answer (score 0):

do a join between all the tables as below which will get you the matched rows

```
select m.id as makeId,
t.id as trimid,
t.trim_name,
t.model_id
from Makes m
inner join Models mo 
on m.id = mo.make_id
inner join Trims t
on t.model_id = mo.id
inner join Forsale_Cars fc
on fc.trim_id = t.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You want

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Trims t
INNER JOIN             -- it will get us only existing 
    Models m
ON
    t.model_id = m.id
INNER JOIN
    Forsale_Cars fc
ON
    t.id = fc.trim_id
WHERE
    m.make_id = <user input>
```

Through the use of INNER JOINs you will only get existing trims that are listed in Forsale_Cars.

Answer (score -1):

It is not really clear how to do this using only the schema information (tables, attributes) you provide. This would be easier if you were to provide us with the data model that connects your tables. See:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model

Presumably Models(make_id) is a foreign key that references attributes in Trims and Forsale_Cars. You should be able to join those tables and select what you are looking for.